# How to get Inline-style strip all text except the number?

Tags: javascript, html, css

How can I get an inline style and strip all text so i can calculate a number to replace a style?  I created a rotate button that will rotate a div 45%. instead of using

```
     document.getElementById('toRotate').style.transform += "rotate(45deg)";
```

which will add an additional rotate to the style each time clicked im tryng to get the rotation number of the style and add 45 to it then replace the amount so i dont end up with this

```
    <div style="transform:rotate(0deg); transform:rotate(45deg); transform:rotate(45deg) " id="toRotate" class="mydiv">My Div</div>
```

I get an error using replace(/[^0-9]/g, '').  Any help with this is appreciated.

```js
function rotateMe() {


  var lineStyle = document.getElementById('toRotate').style;
  var styNum = lineStyle.replace(/[^0-9]/g, '');
  var calAmount = styNum + 45;
  document.getElementById('toRotate').style.transform = "rotate(" + calAmount + "deg)";

  console.log(lineStyle);
  console.log(lineStyle.replace(/[^0-9]/g, ''));
}
```

```css
.mydiv {
  background-color: blue;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  float: left;
  color: #ffffff;
}

#rotateButton {
  width: 80px;
  height: 60px;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div style="transform:rotate(0deg)" id="toRotate" class="mydiv">My Div</div>
<button onclick="rotateMe();" id="rotateButton" type="button">rotate</button>
```

Comment: Why not just store the degrees in a variable as a number, and then increase that number?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a variable and add the angle each time you click

```js
var calAmount =0;
function rotateMe() {
  calAmount+=45;
  document.getElementById('toRotate').style.transform = "rotate(" + calAmount + "deg)";
}
```

```css
.mydiv {
  background-color: blue;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  float: left;
  color: #ffffff;
}

#rotateButton {
  width: 80px;
  height: 60px float:left;
}
```

```html
<div style="transform:rotate(0deg)" id="toRotate" class="mydiv">My Div</div>
<button onclick="rotateMe();" id="rotateButton" type="button">rotate</button>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, Rotate div using transform

```js
function rotateMe() {
  var lineStyle = document.getElementById('toRotate').style;
  var rotate = document.querySelector('input[name="rotate"]:checked').value;
  var styNum = lineStyle.transform.replace(/[^0-9]/g, '');
  var calAmount = 0;  
  var rotateScale = parseInt(document.getElementById('rotatescale').value);

  if(rotate == 'right')
  {
  calAmount = parseInt(styNum) + rotateScale;
  }
  else
  {
  calAmount = (-rotateScale) - parseInt(styNum);
  }
  
  document.getElementById('toRotate').style.transform = "rotate(" + calAmount + "deg)";

  //console.log(calAmount);
  //console.log(lineStyle.replace(/[^0-9]/g, ''));
}
```

```css
.mydiv {
  background-color: blue;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  float: left;
  color: #ffffff;
}

#rotateButton {
  width: 80px;
  height: 60px;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
Rotate Right<input type="radio" checked name="rotate" value="right"> Rotate Left<input type="radio" name="rotate" value="left">
<br/><br/>
<input type="text" id="rotatescale" value="45">
<br/>
<br/>
<div style="transform:rotate(0deg)" id="toRotate" class="mydiv">My Div</div>
<button onclick="rotateMe();" id="rotateButton" type="button">rotate</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a CSS variable (`--rotation`) to store the angle, and use the variable in the CSS as the value of the transform. On each click, get the current value of the variable, add 45 and set it again:

```js
const rotation = '--rotation';
const toRotate = document.querySelector('#toRotate');

function rotateMe() {
  const rotate = parseInt(getComputedStyle(toRotate).getPropertyValue(rotation));
  toRotate.style.setProperty(rotation, `${rotate + 45}deg`);
}
```

```css
.mydiv {
  background-color: blue;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  float: left;
  color: #ffffff;
  --rotation: 45deg;
  transform: rotate(var(--rotation));
}

#rotateButton {
  width: 80px;
  height: 60px;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div id="toRotate" class="mydiv">My Div</div>
<button onclick="rotateMe();" id="rotateButton" type="button">rotate</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

you actualy so close, all you need to do is add ".transform" and "parseInt" and voila..

checkout my snippet, hopefully you have a nice day..

```js
<script>
function rotateMe() {

  //add .transform
  var lineStyle = document.getElementById('toRotate').style.transform;
  
  var styNum = lineStyle.replace(/[^0-9]/g, '');
  
  // add parseInt
  var calAmount = parseInt(styNum) + 45;
  document.getElementById('toRotate').style.transform = "rotate(" + calAmount + "deg)";
;
}
</script>
```